# Уведомление о регистрации у нового участника ведёт на страницу тура на SOen

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, уведомления, тур

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При клике открывается https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

А должна открываться страница https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спросил на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336946/260198).

Это был просто перевод уведомления с английского SO. Такое уведомление приходит на первом сайте сети, где вы регистрируетесь.

Т.е, это в принципе не было уведомление с ruSO.